# What's wrong with my SQL update? Java

Tags: java

```
private void subtractCredit(String accountType){                      //subtract credit by 1
    String CREDITS = "UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET "+accountType+" = "+accountType+" -1, CREDITSUSED=CREDITSUSED+1 WHERE USERNAME='"+username+"'";
    try{
        ps=con.prepareStatement(CREDITS);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public String[] getAccount(String accountType){             //Generate a random account.
    accountType = "Select * FROM "+accountType+" ORDER BY RAND()";  
    String[] arr = new String[2];
    try{
        ps = con.prepareStatement(accountType);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();          
        if(rs.next()){
            arr[0] = rs.getString("USERNAME");
            arr[1] = rs.getString("PASSWORD");
            subtractCredit(accountType);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }        
    return arr;
}
```

Here is the catch exception.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select * FROM
>   TABLE ORDER BY RAND() = Select * FROM TABLE ORDER BY RAND() -1' at
>   line 1

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Does it not strike you as odd that the SQL fragment in the error message (which is indeed screwed up) doesn't look anything like the SQL produced by your method?

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown in that code? The exception is a `SELECT`, but posted code an `UPDATE`

Comment: Did you try to debug your app using the standard debugger?

Comment: This has many indicators for the problems if you type the same error on search engines. I would suggest debug first and then search for the most specific error from within your stack trace.

Comment: @user3320018 - You missed the most important first steps. 1) READ the error message and the rest of the stacktrace, and 2) THINK about it.  Googling should be way down the list of things to do when debugging.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Probably it didn't strike him as odd. But it certainly should have. Did you notice the `catch (Exception ...` abomination?  How he throws away the stack trace by calling `System.out.println(e)`?  How he then just continues after the failure?

Comment: you seem to be passing "Select * FROM "+accountType+" ORDER BY RAND()" into subtractCredit , it end up running  "UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET "Select * FROM "+accountType+" ORDER BY RAND()" = "Select * FROM "+accountType+" ORDER BY RAND()" -1, CREDITSUSED=CREDITSUSED+1 WHERE USERNAME='"+username+"'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's wrong with my SQL update?

The problem is not in your SQL update!!

Look at the SQL in the error message:

```
        Select * FROM TABLE ORDER BY RAND()
```

Questions you should ask yourself:

1. Does that look anything like the update SQL?  Nope!!
2. And what is missing from the 'select'?  There is no table name!

If `getAccount()` is the method that is responsible for this error, then the cause *should be* obvious to anyone who bothers to read the code.  The value of `accountType` is wrong.  If the code is excactly as you have shown us, `accountType` must contain the string `"TABLE"`.  That is not going to work because `TABLE` is an SQL reserved word.  A table called `TABLE` is a schema design error, because it leads to SQL syntax errors.

The other possibility is that the code actually says this:

```
    accountType = "Select * FROM TABLE " + 
            accountType + " ORDER BY RAND()";
```

If so, the problem is that you have called the method with an empty string as the account type.

---

When you have fixed that, I want you to focus on a number of other significant problems in your code:

1. Assembling SQL by string bashing like this:

   ```
   accountType = "Select * FROM "+accountType+" ORDER BY RAND()";
   ```

   is potentially dangerous.  If the value of `accountType` can come from user input, an HTTP request parameter, or anything else that is not under your control, then this code is vulnerable to an SQL injection attack.

   The normal solution is to use a constant SQL string with `?` placeholders, and then inject the actual parameter values using `PreparedStatement.setXxxx` method calls.  Unfortunately, a table name can't be injected that way.
2. Catching `Exception` like you are doing is a BAD IDEA.  Sure, it catches the SQLException that you are anticipating.  The problem is that it *also* catches a bunch of other exceptions that you may not be anticipating.  For example, if the code in the `try` block had a bug that caused it to throw a `NullPointerException` ... you would catch that too.
3. Using `System.out.println(e)` to output a "diagnostic" is bad:

   - For an end user, the exception message is opaque an alarming.
   - For a developer, you really need a stacktrace.
   - Sending developer diagnostics to standard output is generally a bad idea.  Use a logging framework.
4. Your error recovery is almost certainly wrong.  If the SQL query fails, then your `getAccount` method returns an String[2] containing `null` strings.  If the calling code doesn't test for this, then you are likely to get an NPE when you try to use the (bogus) account details.

   The correct thing to do is most likely to throw another exception, or if you don't want to add code to handle this up-stack, then allow the `SQLException` to propagate by removing the try catch ... and declaring the exception in the method signature.
5. This is minor, but most people think that updating the value of a method parameter is bad style.  You are doing this when you assign a new value to `accountType`.  Better style would be to declare a local variable and use that to hold the SQL string.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this sequence of statements (drawn from two methods, but the variable names correspond):

```
getAccount("TABLE");  // inferred

accountType = "Select * FROM "+accountType+" ORDER BY RAND()";  

String CREDITS = "UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET "+accountType+" = "+accountType
        + " -1, CREDITSUSED=CREDITSUSED+1 WHERE USERNAME='"+username+"'";
ps=con.prepareStatement(CREDITS);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

The error indeed occurs in your `UPDATE` statement, but only part of it appears in the message.  The sequence of statements above explains how it got that way.  In particular, consider the effect of the assignment to `accountType` on the subsequent statements.

Comment: You promote the usage of `PreparedStatement` but concatenate the values of the parameters in the String rather than use parameterized parameters in the query and use `PreparedStatement#setXyz`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Unfortunately, you can't inject a table name as a parameter.  So your advice (which is valid) doesn't help in the "select".

Comment: @StephenC I know that. I meant about the second query, the `"UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET " + ... `